# Running levmar c++ in multi-thread (parallel computing)?

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing

I am using http://users.ics.forth.gr/~lourakis/levmar/index.html in my project. I would like to be able to compute things with this in multi-threaded environment where all these threads are computing using levmar in parallel. However, the program kept crashing unless I use thread synchronisation (i.e. having it to run in sequence) or introduce some delay between each evocation of thread. Has anybody had any success using levmar in any form of parallel computing? An example would be nice too. Thanks.

Comment: Is the problem with levmar or the support libraries? levmar recommends using LAPACK. Is LAPACK safe for parallel computing? PLASMA is mentioned as a package for parallel computing.

Comment: That is the part I would like to find out if anybody has actually tried. I have no success at the moment. PLASMA seems to give the parallel computing ability but is that within the levmar itself? I would like to have multiple levmar running at the same time. Was curious if it is possible. But it seems it is worth looking at if the problem exists in LAPACK or CLAPACK.

Comment: Any success with threading `levmar`? I'm very curious because I'm trying to achieve the same thing but `levmar` keeps crashing if I run two threads. Please post your solution as an answer, if you have one.

Comment: I actually managed to get it running in parallel without crashing (but I have seen situation where it is giving back different results, so I don't know if it is a good solution). But the way to do it is to untick LAPACK and LINSOLVERS_RETAIN_MEMORY in CMAKE.